# what does this pointer syntax in C mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I came across to a question from one of my friend.

What is the difference between these?

```
* char ptr
char * ptr
```

Comment: I don't think the first one is valid in C.

Comment: The second one is a valid variable declaration, and the first one is not? I think you need to provide a little more context for your question.

Comment: I've been shocked 'cause of the first one. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error:

```
* char ptr;
```

This declares `ptr` as a variable of type pointer-to-char:

```
char * ptr;
```

Answer (score 3):

The first declaration `* char ptr` is not valid C syntax, so that is why you are getting a compile-time error. The second declaration `char * ptr` is valid C syntax, because the type is listed first followed by the pointer '*' symbol and the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The first line, `* char ptr;`, is not valid.

The second line, `char * ptr;` declares a variable of type *pointer to char*.

Comment: @Adam What are you talking about?

Comment: Each time I tried to read your answer, another text box appeared indicating that it'd just been edited.  I like this version; it matches mine almost perfectly.  :-)

Comment: Well, I just added missing semi-colons and then added the code for line 1. The bulk of the answer was there 3 seconds before yours. At least we agree!  ;-)

Comment: Yea. Thanks. 
I also think the same that first is not valid.